# JS function to count odd numbers and negatives in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, arguments

I'm  currently trying to write a JS function that takes multiple arguments to count or tally the odd numbers and negative numbers in an "array". I put array in quotes because the function actually takes in arguments.

I want to use a for loop to get the odds and negatives, but my code isn't working.

```
function arrayAnalyzer() {

var myArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)

var counter = {
  odds : 0,
  negatives : 0,
  avg : 0,
  median : 0
}

  for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

    if(myArray{i] % 2 === 1) {
       counter.odds++ }

    if(myArray[i] < 0) {
       counter.negatives++ }
    }  

return counter
}

 arrayAnalyzer(7, -3, 0, 12, 44, -5, 3);
```

I've found online that this code works, but I want to use a for-loop if possible.

```
myArray.forEach(function(num){
    if (Math.abs(num) % 2 === 1) counter.odds++
    if (num < 0) counter.negatives++
})
```

Comment: There is a typo in `myArray{i]`... Also, are you sure `myArray` is being populated?

Comment: Just to add on, that `forEach` loop also accounts for negative odd numbers which your `for` loop does not.

Comment: The code seems to work after fixing the `myArray{i]` typo unless I'm missing something. One possible issue: negative odd numbers are not counted.

Comment: Oh geez, that was a very simple mistake. Thank you for catching that. I was debugging on chrome console but for some reason I didn't see that syntax error.  Thank you everyone

@BeardFist You're right, so in this case the forEach would be a better way to do this. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working with a slight syntax fix in your first if statement:

```
function arrayAnalyzer() {

var myArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)

var counter = {
  odds : 0,
  negatives : 0,
  avg : 0,
  median : 0
}

  for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

    if(myArray[i] % 2 === 1) {
       counter.odds++ }

    if(myArray[i] < 0) {
       counter.negatives++ }
    }  

return counter
}
```

working JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/yokawu/edit?js,console